# Building a Expression<Func<T,bool>> which makes use of DbLikeExpression

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I just noticed that there exists `System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.CommandTrees.DbLikeExpression` which seems to be implemented well in both SqlServer and SQLite providers (by implementing `DbExpressionVisitor<>`).

Is this somehow usable when working with Expressions? Can I force an Expression to result in the usage of DbLikeExpression, which both SqlServer and SQLite providers translate into a real `LIKE` SQL clause.
If I just use a simple lambda for the expression -- ex: `user => user.Name.StartsWith("admin")` then the resulting SQL uses `CHARINDEX` instead of `LIKE` which doesn't use indices and therefore is painfully slow.

I'm already using PredicateBuilder (from [LinqKit](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit)) especially for combining with OR or invoking (=expanding) other Expressions, but the resulting Expressions (dumped with LinqPad) are a totally WTF to me.

[Using latest technologies: .NET 4.5.2 and EF 6.1.0]

BTW: This entire question is only the result of finding a workaround for [problems with mapping the SQLite glob function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24043080/using-the-glob-function-in-linq-to-entities)

Comment: I'm not familiar with them, but they don't inherit from `Expression`.  Looks like when an EF provider is given an expression tree it first translates those expressions into its own `DbExpression` objects, and then parses *those* into SQL.  That said, I don't know why the types would be publicly visible if that's all they're used for.

Comment: @Servy there is also `System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.LikeOp` and the namespace `System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler` is making use of both.

Comment: That is consistent with my hypothesis.

Comment: @Servy and there is `System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateFunctionIntoLike((MethodCallExpression call, [..])` which definitely is working against `System.Linq.Expressions.Expression` -- I just wonder why `stringVariable.StartsWith("xyz")` gets translated to "useless" (non-index-using) `CHARINDEX` queries instead if `LIKE`.

Comment: Have you got a more concrete question than "is this somehow usable"? For now, this question is "too broad".

Comment: @GertArnold I updated the text to be more specific

Comment: I don't know which version of ef are you using but for 6.1 StartsWith actually generates Like query.

Comment: @mr100 not for SQLite; and it's implementation for `public override ISqlFragment Visit(DbLikeExpression e)` in class `System.Data.SQLite.SqlGenerator` is creating `LIKE` SQL -- but when I use `StartsWith()` I receive non-index-using `CHARINDEX` function calls.