# Using the GLOB function in LINQ to Entities

Tags: .net, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, system.data.sqlite

I need SQLite's `glob` function in a (C#) method which has to return `Expression<Func<RandomEntity, bool>>` -- and I need `glob` because only then the index is used (already checked using `EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN [..]`).

So I added the following function mapping to `<edmx:StorageModels><Schema>` (SSDL):

```
    <Function Name="glob" Aggregate="false" BuiltIn="true" NiladicFunction="false" IsComposable="true" ReturnType="bit">
        <Parameter Name="pattern" Mode="In" Type="nvarchar"/>
        <Parameter Name="target" Mode="In" Type="nvarchar"/>
    </Function>
```

and a C# stub method:

```
public static class SQLiteFunctions
{
    [DbFunction("Model.Store", "glob")]
    public static bool Glob(string pattern, string target)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException("Only exists for IQueryable/Expression<Func<T,bool>>!");
    }
}
```

and the usage (just a sample producing tiny SQL):

```
var count = context.Users.Count(u => SQLiteFunctions.Glob("admin*", u.Name));
```

While this works the resulting SQL uses a "silly" `= 1` comparison since the model only knows the datatype "bit" (which is 0 or 1) and I found no real boolean type although the native glob function seems to be true boolean:

```
SELECT 
[GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1]
FROM ( SELECT 
    Count([Filter1].[A1]) AS [A1]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        1 AS [A1]
        FROM [Users] AS [Extent1]
        WHERE (glob('admin*', [Extent1].[Name])) = 1
    )  AS [Filter1]
)  AS [GroupBy1]
```

**The problem**: This way (with "= 1") SQLite doesn't use the index and the query is badly slow. If I remove the 3 characters "= 1" the query becomes fast and also the query plan changes from "SCAN TABLE" to "SEARCH TABLE USING INDEX".

Any ideas how to make the function a true boolean function?

---

Addition:

I also tried using the CSDL section ():

```
    <Function Name="GlobMatch" ReturnType="Edm.Boolean">
        <Parameter Name="globPattern" Type="Edm.String" />
        <Parameter Name="target" Type="Edm.String" />
        <DefiningExpression> glob(globPattern, target) </DefiningExpression>
    </Function>
```

and

```
    [DbFunction("DoPiMo", "GlobMatch")]
    public static bool Glob2(string globPattern, string target)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException("Only exists for IQueryable/Expression<Func<T,bool>>!");
    }
```

but this only produces a runtime error saying "glob" is not defined/known.

Comment: @ErikEJ sorry, pasted wrong code.. using "string" the usage code `context.Users.Count()` would not even compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When doing a prefix search with LIKE or GLOB, SQLite rewrites it as two comparisons.

You could just write the two comparisons directly:

```
u.Name >= "admin" and u.Name < "admio"
```

Comment: This looks promising - but I now have to find a pattern for the exclusive right side comparison. Will there be problems when the index is `BINARY` but the DB/connection is configured to be case-insensitive?

Comment: The collation of the index must be the same as the collation used by the comparison.