# Return types of glob() and like() and failure of using index although 'LIKE optimization' applies

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-execution-plan

I'm writing this finding due to auto-created SQL by EntityFramework (see [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24043080/using-the-glob-function-in-linq-to-entities)):

When returning the result of `glob()` (or `like()`) it appears that the type of these functions is `bit`:

```
SELECT Name, glob('admin*', Name) as globresult
FROM Users
```

returns for example (it's really just an example, I'm NOT doing such user searches):

```
Name            globresult
Administrator   1
Springy         0
```

But when using it this way in a `WHERE` clause the query plan (extracted with `EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN [..]`) changes from good (=using index) to bad:

**GOOD:**

```
SELECT FolderID, Name
FROM Folders
WHERE glob('1_2_*', RootPath)
```

Query plan:

```
0   0   0   SEARCH TABLE Folders USING INDEX IX_RootPath (RootPath>? AND RootPath<?)
```

**BAD:** (only difference is the `= 1` comparison)

```
SELECT FolderID, Name
FROM Folders
WHERE glob('1_2_*', RootPath) = 1
```

Query plan:

```
0   0   0   SCAN TABLE Folders
```

Qualifies this for a bug report or is there a reason why this should be by design?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLite recognizes columns to be used in index lookups only when they are used directly in an expression in a WHERE clause:

```
x = 5  AND  y GLOB 'x*'
```

Any more complex expression (such as `(x = 5) = 1` or even `+x = 5`) prevents the optimizer from recognizing a supported pattern (and this [is documented](http://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html#uplus)).
While the meaning of these expression is actually the same, the optimizer lacks the code to be able to *prove* it.